# Aurora Postgres CDC

Tags: change-data-capture

I have setup a DMS task with CDC to continue to replicate data changes from DB2 to Postgres. Users now want to read and write to the Postgres database simultaneously. Can users write to the database while a DMS CDC replication task is setup and running?

Additionally, if CDC was running for an extended time in production, could there be any impact to current DB2 production and if so what would these concerns be?

Thanks